# Encoding variables

Tags: list-manipulation, fitting

I'm trying to fit a Logistic Model using `LogitModelFit` in Mathematica.

The data I'm using contain qualitative variables that I have to encode.

I've searched in the documentation but I haven't been able to find any such function. Does Mathematica have such a function? If not, why?¹

```
{{"No", 729.526, 44361.6, "No"},
 {"Yes", 817.18, 12106.1,  "No"},
 {"No", 1073.55, 31767.1, "No"},
 {"No", 529.251, 35704.5, "No"},
 {"No", 785.656, 38463.5, "No"},
 {"Yes", 919.589, 7491.56, "No"},
 {"No", 825.513, 24905.2, "No"},
 {"Yes", 808.668, 17600.5, "No"},
 {"No", 1161.06, 37468.5, "No"},
 {"No", 0, 29275.3, "No"}}
```

¹ I know it's possible to write one, but I'm trying to figure out why wouldn't Mathematica have something like that (if in fact it doesn't).

Comment: The function is `ReplaceAll`. Assuming that the encoding that you want is `{"Yes"->1, "No"->0}` just use `list /. {"Yes"->1, "No"->0}`.

Comment: I was using `Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]], <|"No" -> 0, "Yes" -> 1|>@#[[4]]} &, 
  data];`. That's even simpler, thanks!! Please make that an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is `ReplaceAll`. Assuming that the encoding that you want is `{"Yes"->1, "No"->0}`:

```
list = {{"No", 729.526, 44361.6, "No"},
   {"Yes", 817.18, 12106.1, "No"},
   {"No", 1073.55, 31767.1, "No"},
   {"No", 529.251, 35704.5, "No"},
   {"No", 785.656, 38463.5, "No"},
   {"Yes", 919.589, 7491.56, "No"},
   {"No", 825.513, 24905.2, "No"},
   {"Yes", 808.668, 17600.5, "No"},
   {"No", 1161.06, 37468.5, "No"},
   {"No", 0, 29275.3, "No"}};

encodedList = list /. {"Yes" -> 1, "No" -> 0}
```

> {{0, 729.526, 44361.6, 0}, {1, 817.18, 12106.1, 0}, {0, 1073.55,
>   31767.1, 0}, {0, 529.251, 35704.5, 0}, {0, 785.656, 38463.5, 0}, {1, 919.589, 
>     7491.56, 0}, {0, 825.513, 24905.2, 0}, {1, 808.668, 17600.5, 0}, {0, 
>     1161.06, 37468.5, 0}, {0, 0, 29275.3, 0}}

Answer (score 3):

[`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) is highly concise, which I like, but as an alternative you may consider applying a specific transformation function to only the parts of your data that need it using [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html):

```
(* list = your data *)

enc["Yes"] = 1;
enc["No"]  = 0;

MapAt[enc, list, {All, {1, 4}}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 729.526, 44361.6, 0}, {1, 817.18, 12106.1, 0}, {0, 1073.55, 31767.1, 0}, . . .}
> ```

Comment: Interesting suggestion! I definitely see a need for this in some cases.